# How to move directory via SSH?

Tags: ssh, mv

I want to move a the whole 'includes' folder (whole folder with all its files and subfolders) that is located on /site/«HERE»
to one folder up (..) via SSH. Can anybody please tell me how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: StackExchange is for programming questions. This is off-topic and likely belongs on ServerFault. That said, you can just `mv ./dir ../` to move a file or folder from the current working directory to the parent directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ssh user@server mv /site/includes /
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are logged in already, try this

```
mv original_file new_name
```